# This performs the Or8Way function, Why is the or1out[1] 0?

Tags: hdl, nand2tetris

Shouldn't it be 1 ( 1or1 = 1; 1or0 = 1)

[image: screen shot of hdl]

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text *as text* into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or8way takes a 8bit bus as input and outputs a single bit bus. That bit is 1 if *any* of the bits in the input are 1, and 0 if *all* of the bits in the input are 0. Thus, there really is no or1out[1]. There is only or1out, a single-bit signal.

You can confirm this by looking at the definition comment for Or8Way:

```
/**
 * 8-way Or: 
 * out = (in[0] or in[1] or ... or in[7])
 */
```